# Cross domain request using jquery JSONP bult in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to implement a click button that downloads library (zip file) from non-local server. The task is simple: if you hit the URL you will have the zip file downloaded. I read in the internet that there is a restriction about cross-domain request, but there is also a workaround for that. So in the code below I applied one of the workarounds using jquery.

I tried ti simulate that click via this code:

```
    $.ajax({
      type:     "GET",
      url:      "http://www.touchwand.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Icons-and-backgrounds.zip",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

Gues what. Doesnt work. The file is not downloaded.

I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

It is may be due to the returned response format is not JSON. But please tell me hot make it work?

*** EDIT ***

Changed the code to report errors.

The result is:

[image]

The request status is `200`

Comment: What line throws that error?

Comment: @Adelin 
Changed the code and posted the results.

Comment: Well you can see it yourself that the error comes from another file, not `scripts.js`

Comment: Why is JavaScript/AJAX involved _at all_ here? A simple `<a href="http://www.touchwand.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Icons-and-backgrounds.zip">Download ZIP file</a>` should do perfectly, no …?

Comment: @CBroe
Upvote for you answer. It does the magic. Still wy is it not working bothers me.